# Js, как получить this класса в методе без bind?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

Как получить this класса, внутри метода класса, не прибегая к bind? Т.к в этом методе нужен свой this.

К примеру:

```
export default class test extends Component {

  constructor() {

    this.state = {
      loaded: false
    };

  }

  getParentThis() { //Принимает из вне элемент, к которому мы можем обратиться через this, но так же нам нужно свойство loaded

  console.log(this.state); //Если не сделать bind в вызове функции, показывает undefined, но если сделать, теряется переданный элемент 

  }

}
```

Comment: Какой элемент? Можно пример? В вашем коде не видно, что нужен свой `this`

Comment: При любом раскладе есть только два способа, первый bind, а второй создать свойство значение которого будет стрелочная функция в которой будет вызываться нужный Вам метод. Естественно выываемый метод переквалифицируется в разряд "приватных", а свойство в "публичное".